# Should seeds be seeded despite non-reproducible results due to GPU?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory, random-seed

I would like to train a CNN-architecture several times with GPU in Google Colab (Tensorflow+Keras) with the same training dataset, and then test each of these trained models with the same testing dataset. Then I want to determine the mean and standard deviation from the results (accuracys) to evaluate the performance of the CNN. (I would like to train the CNN architecture repeatedly because no reproducible results are possible due to GPU).

I wonder if I should not put different seeds on each run to at least limit the randomness a bit?

So far, I have set the following seeds whose values I vary from run to run, except for `os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED']='0'`, of which I am not sure if I should put this at all?

```
import os
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import random as rn

os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED']='0'
np.random.seed(1)
rn.seed(2)
tf.set_random_seed(1)
```

What do you think about that? Should I set the seeds or should I not set any seeds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume that you would like to get a number or a confidence interval of the model performance. In that case you would like the performance to account for all sources of randomness: initialization, data shuffling, nondeterministic ops, etc. Which means that you should keep your seeds random.

Setting the seeds to constant values might not make your model immediately deterministic. Yet, at the very least, it should make you weight initialization deterministic, which ofter has a signifficant impact on the final performance i.e. be a major source of randomness. I would recommend only fixing you seeds/initializations if you are performing some fine grain experiments and you would expect that effects of performance improvement can be harder to see due to random init effects.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the seeds is not useful unless you are trying to make perfectly-reproducible results. Since that does not appear to be your goal, I would suggest not setting any seeds.